# How can I pack an int as 32 bits big endian in Perl?

Tags: perl, binary, endianness

Consider this snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = "1";
my $packed = pack("I",$data);
open(my $file,">","test.bin") || die "error $!\n";
binmode $file;
print $file $packed;
```

The thing is, trying to read it from another language, this appears to be little endian. Is there any template argument that allows me to write it as big endian? I'd like to avoid doing extra work when reading.

Comment: Do you mean 32 *bits* or 32 *bytes* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the "N" template with pack:

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html

Answer (score 3):

The solution is the `N` template.

```
my $packed = pack "N", $data;
```

See the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) documentation for a list of all pack options.

Comment: As of Perl 5.10 you can also use byte-order modifiers (`<` and `>`). They aren't necessary here but they're a godsend for quad words and floating point.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks! Seems that `I>` also produces the right result.